# Synology File Station API GET request syntax explained

Tags: python, syntax, request, synology

I am working on an application using the Synology File Station API with python but I am having a bit of trouble understanding the get request syntax.

Here is an example of a get request from the documenation:

```
GET /webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Search&version=2&method=start&
folder_path=%5B%22%2Fvideo%22%5D&pattern=1
```

In the *folder_path* parameter what does the %5B%22%2F preceding the folder path name (in this case *video*) mean? Sorry if this is a trivial question but I am unable to find anything in the documentation that explains this.

Here is a link to the documentation for reference: https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Package/FileStation/All/enu/Synology_File_Station_API_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

the string is URL encoded ( character replaced by their ASCII values)

see [url decoder](https://www.urldecoder.org/)

In this case, **%5B%22%2Fvideo%22%5D** represents: **["/video"]**